# Minikube Ingress Does not resolve but minikube IP does

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am running a simple pod with an image from local image registry in a minikube cluster on Windows 10. I am also running a simple nodeport service. The container is available when I try accessing it from the browser with <minikube_ip>:30080.

However, now I want to set an ingress controller because I want to set up a domain and not access it using the IP. The ingress works for something simple like a basic nginx pod, but does not work for this pod that I'm trying to use. I was previously using jwilder/nginx-proxy in docker-compose and it had some conf files that needed to be attached in the conf.d directory. However, since I am moving to Kubernetes, I thought to totally omit the conf files and the reverse proxy image.

Now after the hosts fie is updated, the domain is reachable via curl, the domain is also pingable, however, it simply cannot be reached on the browser.

pod-yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: api
  name: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: api
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: DEV_PORT
          value: "80"
        image: localhost:5000/api:2.3
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        name: api
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
status: {}
```

Service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\Users\***kompose.exe
      convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: api
  name: api
spec:
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: api
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: "http"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30080
```

Ingress.yaml

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 # for versions before 1.14 use extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: tls-ingress
 spec:
   tls:
     - secretName: oaky-tls
       hosts: 
         - api.localhost
   rules:
   - host: api.localhost
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /
         backend:
           serviceName: api
           servicePort: 80
```

I have checked and the TLS secret is available, I am not understanding the issue here and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Checked this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/ ?

Comment: This is hello world ingress, I have already done everything of this, and this tests via curl and as per the question, I don't have an issue with curl, just an issue with the browser

Comment: There is no need for ingress to point to a NodePort backend. Can you change the service type to ClusterIP please? Can you also verify how you are hitting the ingress? Does it have a service with an external IP? What ingress controller do you have deployed?

Comment: I am using nginx ingress controller, which comes as a minikube addon by default. I have changed the type to clusterIP now. When I execute logs on the ingress-controller pod, it gives me results for the curl requests but not browser ones.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
Chrome was overlooking the etc hosts file, so I did the following:

- Switched to Firefox and instantly the URLs were working.
- Added annotations to denote the class:

> kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

- Added annotations to make sure requests are redirected to ssl

> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"

Comment: Good solution Mr, now it is working for me. But do you have any idea why chrome does these things??? and also is there anything we can configure chrome to not do these things anymore?